# How is $\int_0^{\frac12}\left(\frac14-x^2\right)^4dx=\frac12\int_0^1x^4(1-x)^4dx?$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Let $J=\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac12}\left(\frac14-x^2\right)^4dx, K=\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac12}x^4(1-x)^4dx$ then which of the following hold(s) good?
>
> - A) $\dfrac JK=2$
> - B) $J-K=0$
> - C) $J=\frac12\displaystyle\int_0^1x^4(1-x)^4dx$
> - D) $K=\dfrac1{1260}$

**My Attempt:**
$$J=\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac12}\left(\frac14-\left(\frac12-x\right)^2\right)^4dx\\=\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac12}(x^2-x)^4dx=\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac12}x^4(x-1)^4dx=K$$

So, option A is incorrect. B is correct.

For, C) If I put, $2x=t\implies2dx=dt,$ then

$$J=\frac12\displaystyle\int_0^1\left(\frac14-\frac{t^2}4\right)^4dt$$

Not able to finish it.

Comment: Have you tried factorizing $\frac{1}{4} - x^2$ into $(\frac{1}{2} - x)(\frac{1}{2} + x)$?

Comment: @Zhanxiong Earlier I had done that to prove $J=K$. I didn't try this for C)

Comment: It should be immediate, after you did the factorization, then let $u = \frac{1}{2} + x$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong but the limit is not matching.

Comment: Got it. Will post my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$I=\displaystyle\int_0^1x^4(1-x)^4dx=\displaystyle\int_0^{2\cdot\frac12}x^4(1-x)^4dx$$

Using the formula, $$\int_0^{2a}f(x)dx=\displaystyle\int_0^a(f(x)+f(2a-x))dx$$

I get, $$I=\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac12}[x^4(1-x)^4+(1-x)^4x^4]dx\\I=2K=2J$$

Thus, $J=\frac 12I$

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}x^4(1-x)^4dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}x^4(1-x)^4dx+\frac{1}{2}\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}x^4(1-x)^4dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}K+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}t^4(1-t)^4dt=\frac{1}{2}K+\frac{1}{2}K=J$$

using the substitution $t=1-x$ and the fact that $J=K$.